# what does compiler do with "using namespace" directive?

Tags: c++, namespaces

i know that a using directive lets us use code from a specific
namespace without explicitly typing the namespace.

but what does the compiler exactly do with a using directive? does it bring all code from that specific namespace into the global namespace?

Comment: `does it bring all code from that specific namespace into the global namespace?` No

Comment: Have you already seen [cppreference.com - Using-directives](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace#Using-directives)?

Comment: It's less "haul the things from that other place into here" and more "look in this other place even if I don't explicitly say so".

Comment: Also it has nothing to do with "*global namespace*" but the "*current namespace*".

Comment: @rustyx you are right, i have just been repeatedly using std as global namespace, but you are definitely correct

Comment: @Scheff i have, i just would like to know what the compiler actually does, because its very confusing to me how the compiler will do such a thing for us

Comment: @molbdnilo so the compiler decided that "that piece of code doesn't exist in the global namespace, i will go look for it in the specified namespace" , or will the linker actually help with this?

Comment: Namespaces are something which is processed in the compiler only. (It probably handles symbol tables somewhere which may be connected somehow. There will be nothing of it in the resulting binary - ignoring that it might effect name mangling and become visible in the exported symbols somehow.) So, it's rather hidden how the compiler handles this internally - but probably in the most efficient way. Only, the effect is visible. `using namespace std;` injects the symbols of `std` in the current namespace. This may (or may not) result in collisions when compiling the source.

Comment: Consider the compiler having many containers of symbols.  Let's call each container a *namespace*.  The compiler may also have a list of containers to search.  By default, the *global* namespace is the only container to search.  The `using namespace` will add the specified container of symbols to the present (active) container of symbols.  So, if your code is in the global namespace and the compiler encounters the `using namespace std`, then all the `std::` symbols, that were encountered, will be added to the global symbols container.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews that's actually intuitive and makes a lot of sense